# How to set comma separated values in cookies

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

when i try to set cookie in the following way the values show me in the browser for the cookies are like this 
cookie name -> recent     and    value  1%2c2
where 1 and 2 are my get parameters and %2c i dont know what is this i wants , in place of %2c

```
if(!empty($_GET['c']))
{
    $c = $_GET['c'];
    if(isset($_COOKIE['recent']))
    {
        $c=$_COOKIE['recent'].','.$c;
        setcookie('recent',$c);
    }
    else
    {
        if(setcookie('recent',$c))
        {
            echo "yes";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "no";
        }
    }
}
echo $_COOKIE['recent'];
```

Comment: What are the initial values for `$c` and `$d`? Also, you're missing a semi-colon on line #5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Note that the value portion of the cookie will automatically be
>   urlencoded when you send the cookie, and when it is received, it is
>   automatically decoded and assigned to a variable by the same name as
>   the cookie name.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.urlencode.php

Comment: You don't need to use `urlencode()` or `urldecode()`. As you quoted in your answer, this happens automatically

Comment: Maybe this is a bug, try explode(',',$_COOKIE['some_cookie']); and it doesn't work on a comma-delimited list.  But if you assign the cookie to $some_cookie first and then do explode(',',$some_cookie); it works.  So I don't think you can assume the cookie is always automatically decoded.

Comment: Works; var_dump() your cookie and you'll see commas